# Displaying an imageicon in eclipse doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, imageicon

So I've just written down some simple code that just displays an image in a JButton.
What I have done is write the code:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main extends JFrame{

public static ImageIcon bf;
public static JPanel p;
public static JButton b;

public static void main (String args[]){
    Main main = new Main();

    bf = new ImageIcon("car.png");
    p = new JPanel();
    b = new JButton(bf);
    p.add(b);
    main.add(p);

    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(main.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setSize(600,700);


}

}
```

And I have copied a pic named car.png in the same folder with my class, but I can't seem to get it to work in elipse.

[image]

But when I run the same exact code in BlueJ it runs it without any known issues.
Any help woul be greately apprecciated
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Does it work if you use an absolute path to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
bf = new ImageIcon("car.png");
```

to

```
    URL url = Main.class.getResource("car.png");
    bf = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much..Could you please explain what I did wrong?

Comment: your intentions were not wrong, but how could you provide the path of the image from the context your program was launched. That url represents nothing but the absolute path of your image and its not the source location but the directory where your classes are compiled by eclipse (print that url in syso to know it), check your project-workspace/bin directory, You will find your compiled classes(and resources in source packages if any) in their respective packages, which will be packaged in jar too. seems, you have put your image as well as src file in default package (discouraged by eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

Check that if `car.png` is under the `bin` directory in the filesystem (it is filtered out in Eclipse, so do it in a file explorer).

Btw I would suggest using something like `ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource("/car.png"))`. The reason is the following: later on you will probably package your app (into a Jar file for example). Now if you do it this way, Java is able to locate the image even if it is executed as a Jar or from

Comment: Yeah I checked it and the car.png was in the bin older in the projects' folder

Comment: I recall an issue that these images are found only if they are placed into to root folder of the project (_not_ into the `src` folder).

Comment: would you care to elaborate on what you mean by root folder?

Comment: The folder that contains the `src` folder (the `Test` folder).